# Google Play Services authentification in client-server application

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm developing a client and a server for online game. To make login process easier for users we planning to make enter in game via Google Play Services account.

The problem is that authentification proceeds on client side only, but server needs to create some account for authetificated user too, to store info about his achievements, items and so on.

The question is - how to do it? Which info from Player Services we could store to create account, and authentificate user in further?

Maybe someone had similair experience, i think there should be some simple solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to setup your Google Play Service using client-server, then I think this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/serverlogin) can help you with that. It explains here the step by step procedure that you need to do in order to setup the Google Play Service. For more information just read the above link and check this [thread](https://community.unity.com/t5/Platforms/Please-help-Client-Server-authentication-for-Google-Play/td-p/1749483). Also, if you want the client-only then this [link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/clientsetup) will help you.